# Django querying models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make a query that performs the same task as the my sql query given below

```
SELECT 
    max(date),
    business_id,
    visits
FROM 
data_traffic 
where 
business_id 
IN (
    SELECT 
        competitor_id 
    FROM 
    data_business_competitors WHERE business_id = 868
)
order by
date desc
```

I have written a query given below but it does not gives the visits

```
TrafficData.objects.filter(business_id__in=competitors).values('business_id').annotate(max_date=Max('date'))
```

Comment: You always can use a raw query https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/ to run your sql query

Comment: `business__id__in` was that a typo? (`business__id` --> `business_id`)

Comment: Also, `.values('business_id')` you are only asking for the `business_id`s, so of course it will not "give the visits". Or maybe I am misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this may do it

```
TrafficData.objects\
           .filter(business_id__in=competitors)\
           .annotate(max_date=Max('date'))\
           .order_by('-max_date')\
           .values('business_id', 'visits', 'max_date')
```